# Get little endian paragraph title shape

Tags: line-breaking, titles, books, rendering

As you can see in the MWE, I customize the chapter titles to be displayed in the center of the page with:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\centering\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

So, when I have a little bit long title, the break line come in each line at soon as possible. Then the paragraph title appear as a “big endian” pyramid (triangle in fact…).

For example, with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\centering\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Justification de l’étendue terminologique}

\end{document}
```

I get this rendering:

[image: Default behaviour]

When the expected result is:

[image]

I know I can use the optional argument of `\chapter` command like `\chapter[Justification de l’étendue terminologique]{Justification de\\ l’étendue terminologique}`.

But my goal is to make LaTeX do it himself, without force me to do it manually. So, is their some package or something to get this behavior for titles?

Comment: Add the `[newlinetospace]` option on loading  titlesec: it removes any `\\\`  or `\\\*` from toc and headers.

Comment: tex doesn't make the linebreak "as soon as possible" in fact in the case that you show you want the line break to be _earlier_   not later. As always tex does not consider linebreaks one at a time, but as a least cost minimisation over the whole paragraph. If you want a strong triangular shape you could try shapepar, if you just want normal breaking but each line shorter than the previous, it's a bit hard to do automatocally

Comment: So, @DavidCarlisle you correctly understand my need. Then your advices are helpful. I’ll try to remember it when I’ll had to make it. And yes, my goal is not to get a hard triangle (it could be ugly) but just a triangle-like text.

Comment: are the titles likely to be more than two lines? it's easier to arrange a single linebreak in a two line case than try to control the shape of a whole pargraph